# object doesn't support this property or method 'scrollBy'

Tags: reactjs, webpack, microsoft-edge

I implemented an application using react and webpack. I just saw an error on Microsoft Edge that says :

> object doesn't support this property or method 'scrollBy'

Even though I added babel-polyfil and transform-object-rest-spread.
Could anyone help me?

Comment: What is the full error message? It should be something like elementId.scrollBy(number). type elementId in your console to ensure that it is in the DOM when you do the call...your source code, showing where in the DOM it is called. eg. before body closure. in onload event handler. should indicate if the element has been successfully added to the DOM. Its important that you include reproduction code or links to your website with your questions.

Answer (score 0):

Edge does not support element.scrollBy (but does partially support window.scrollBy).

My workaround in React:
create a ref to the element you wish to scroll, add event listener for mouse scroll,

```
if (/Edge/.test(navigator.userAgent)) {
  this.element.scrollTop = this.element.scrollTop + someDistance;
} else {
  this.element.scrollBy({
    top: someDistance,
    behavior: 'smooth',
  });
}
```

where someDistance is negative/positive depending on scroll direction.